# What is the significance of "tab" e.g. in "crontab" or "inittab"?

Tags: terminology

What does the "tab" mean in "crontab" or "inittab"?
Having some idea of its meaning might help to mentally categorise files which contain the "tab" suffix and understand their relationship with the other parts of an OS.

Comment: Dont forget `fstab`

Comment: @casey good point - I took a look just now - it  also has tabular type organisation of data

Comment: And of course, the tab-key on your keyboard is for tabular formatting, i.e. for tables. They all mean the same.

Comment: `find /etc -type f -name '*tab'`

Comment: I have just expanded the answer, including @casey suggestion about fstab

Answer (score 52):

As for as the names of (crontab) cron table, (inittab) init table and (fstab) filesystem tables: as far as I know, besides the obvious association of `tab` with "table", it means they are the main files for configuring those actions.

The short names are probably also due to the nature of Unix of being practical and using terse commands.

Furthermore in old days teletype terminals were slow.

It must be noted the concepts of `crontab`, `initab` and `fstab` are fairly old in the Unix lore.

We could also make speculations as most of the contemporary filesystems had severe limitations on the length of filenames, that they were kept intentionally short for compatibility reasons or for facilitating browsing backups on foreign (file)systems. [ or bootstraping toolchains ]

The manpage for Vixie `crontab` specifically mentions the tables: `crontab` is the program used to install, deinstall or list the tables used to drive the cron(8) daemon in Vixie Cron.

The crontab(5) page for ISC (old Vixie) cron has as name "crontab - tables for driving cron".

In the AT&T user manuals:

- `inittab` is described as "script for the init process" in the System V manual;
- `mnttab` is described as "mounted file system *tab*" both in the System III and the System V manuals;

Interestingly, both `initab` and `mnttab` seem to be the oldest references found of *tab files.

Comment: cool, makes sense,as  its tabulated data

Comment: I could also swear they are very ancient in what touchs Unix history. Maybe their name also is historically like that due to limitations on the number of characters allowed for the name of files on the first Unix filesystems. Cannot swear on this though.

Comment: More likely the "tab" versus "table" was due to a preference by Unix developers for abbreviating everything to reduce typing.  Recall that command-history was not one of the first-implemented features...

Comment: Also to reduce printing. I believe many early unix machines didn't have screens and instead printed everything entered and output to the command line interface.

Comment: Manpage for `Vixie crontab` even specifically mentions `the tables`: `crontab is the program used to install, deinstall or list the tables used to drive the cron(8) daemon in Vixie Cron.`

Comment: Also, some very early OSs had an 8-character limit on commands and file names; "crontable" would be 9 characters. This is purely speculation, but even if early Unix didn't have this limitation, it's possible that the commands were kept under the limit "just in case" and although "initable" is 8 characters it was also shortened for consistency. (Also, it could be misread as "init-able".)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I think Unix started out [_wthout filename limits_](http://cs-exhibitions.uni-klu.ac.at/index.php?id=216) ! Remember that the Unix designers were also C designers. The C string type is zero-terminated and therefore not artificially length-limited. File names may very well have been implemented the same.

Comment: probably some confusion of mine, I do recall something about in the earlier days of *at least* 13-14 characters.

Comment: @MSalters on what system is that file called "initab" and not "inittab"?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro true, older commonly used filesystems like Minix (as used by very early Linux) and v6/v7  had a limit to 14 bytes for filenames - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: I remember 6 character file name limits on some old OS I used.  I was thinking it was *nix based, but perhaps not...

Comment: This answer would be great if all of this history were incorporated into it.

Comment: @MSalters Unix filenames were limited to 14 characters. It would have severely complicated the design of the filesystem to allow arbitrary-length strings.

Comment: @Random832: You're right, [better link](http://www.utdallas.edu/~venky/os/Proj/disk.pdf)

Comment: I am incorporating some of the more relevant answers here in the answer, will all due respect to the people who remembered them.

Comment: @MSalters, wrong. FIrst Unix systems had directories that were an array of 16-byte entries (2 for inode number, 14 for (non-'\0'-ended, '\0'-filled) filename). I know this because we used to have an IBM RT with such a filesystem way back...